# Complex Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a linear, bounded, self-adjoint operator in a complex Hilbert space $H$. Show that for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, we have
$$
|\langle x, (T-\lambda)x\rangle| \geq |Im(\lambda)|\;\;|| x||^{2},
$$
for all $x \in H$. 
Suppose now that for a certain $\lambda_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, holds the equality for all $x \in H$. What can be concluded about $T$ in this case?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: What is $R(\lambda)$ ? The real part of $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ ?

Comment: @Rebellos sorry. This is the imaginary part of $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. I change the notation. Thanks.

Comment: @Adriano I don't understand this exercise. Mainly the second part where the question asks to draw conclusions about T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $|\langle x, (T-\lambda)x\rangle| = |\langle x,Tz\rangle| - (Re(\lambda)+iIm(\lambda))||x||^{2}.$ Now, we can use the propriety $\langle x,Tx\rangle = \langle Tx, x\rangle = \overline{\langle x,Tx\rangle}$ because $T$ is self-adjoint. Then 
$$
Re(\langle x, (T-\lambda)x\rangle) = \langle x, Tx\rangle - Re(\lambda)||x||^{2}
$$ 
and
$$
Im(\langle x, (T-\lambda)x\rangle) = -Im(\lambda)||x||ˆ{2}.
$$ 
So, the result of the first part is proven.
The second part you need to do some counts here (try to prove that):
$$
0 = \langle y+iz, (T-Re(\lambda_0))y+iz\rangle = 2i\langle y, (T-Re(\lambda_0))z\rangle, \; \forall y, z.
$$ 
This implies that $Tz = Re(\lambda_0)z, \forall z \in H$.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to understand the second part. I appreciated that.